# Trying to make calculator and have one little problem

Tags: javascript, dom, numbers

I am trying to make a calculator and I have a small problem. I have created a function that should show the user the final result, but every time the final result is undefined, but in console my function have a right answer. Can you help me please? I don't beg you for recreating all of my code, just wanna know what is my problem.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id='calculatorOutput' type="text">
  <button class="numberButtons" >0</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >1</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >2</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >3</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >4</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >5</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >6</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >7</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >8</button>
  <button class="numberButtons" >9</button>
  <button class="operatorButtons">+</button>
  <button class="operatorButtons">-</button>
  <button class="operatorButtons">*</button>
  <button class="operatorButtons">/</button>
  <button id="equalButton">=</button>
  <button id="resetButton">С</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.numberButtons');
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.operatorButtons');
let calculatorOutput = document.getElementById('calculatorOutput');
const equalButton = document.getElementById('equalButton');
const resetButton = document.getElementById('resetButton');
let firstNumber = 0;
let operator = '';
let secondNumber = 0;
let finalNumber = 0;
let displayValue = '';

function add(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    console.log(firstNumber + secondNumber);
}

function substract(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    console.log(firstNumber - secondNumber);
}

function multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    console.log(firstNumber * secondNumber);
}

function divide(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    console.log(firstNumber / secondNumber);
}

function operate(firstNumber, operator, secondNumber) {
    if(operator === '+') {
            add(firstNumber, secondNumber) 
  }
  
  else if(operator === '-') {
    substract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  }
  
  else if(operator === '*') {
        multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber) 
  }
  
  else if(operator === "/") {
            divide(firstNumber, secondNumber) 
  }
}

numberButtons.forEach(singleButton =>  {
        singleButton.addEventListener('click', ()  => {
        calculatorOutput.value += singleButton.textContent;
            displayValue = calculatorOutput.value;
            console.log(displayValue);
    })
});

operatorButtons.forEach(singleOperatorButton => {
        singleOperatorButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                calculatorOutput.value = '';
            firstNumber = displayValue;
                displayValue = '';
                operator = singleOperatorButton.textContent;
                /* console.log(`Operator: ${operator}`);
                console.log(`First number : ${firstNumber}; display value ${displayValue}`); */
    })
});

equalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            secondNumber = displayValue;
      /* console.log(`secondNumber : ${secondNumber}`); */
            finalNumber = operate(Number(firstNumber), operator, Number(secondNumber));
            console.log(finalNumber);
})

resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            calculatorOutput.value = '';
      displayValue = '';
})
```

Comment: I think you need to return the values in the functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, return doesn't fix my problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `add`, `substract`, `multiply`, `divide` and `operate` functions are missing their `return` statements.

Right now you just log the values, that's why in the console you see the right result (coming from the `console.log()`s in `add`, `substract`, `multiply` or `divide`) but `operate` never gets that same value or return it to the calling function, which just gets `undefined`.

Here's the updated code:

```js
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.numberButtons');
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.operatorButtons');
let calculatorOutput = document.getElementById('calculatorOutput');
const equalButton = document.getElementById('equalButton');
const resetButton = document.getElementById('resetButton');
let firstNumber = 0;
let operator = '';
let secondNumber = 0;
let finalNumber = 0;
let displayValue = '';

function add(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    return firstNumber + secondNumber;
}

function substract(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    return firstNumber - secondNumber;
}

function multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    return firstNumber * secondNumber;
}

function divide(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    return firstNumber / secondNumber;
}

function operate(firstNumber, operator, secondNumber) {
    if(operator === '+') return add(firstNumber, secondNumber) 
    if(operator === '-') return substract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
    if(operator === '*') return multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber) 
    if(operator === "/") return divide(firstNumber, secondNumber) 
}

numberButtons.forEach(singleButton =>  {
        singleButton.addEventListener('click', ()  => {
        calculatorOutput.value += singleButton.textContent;
            displayValue = calculatorOutput.value;
            console.log(displayValue);
    })
});

operatorButtons.forEach(singleOperatorButton => {
        singleOperatorButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                calculatorOutput.value = '';
            firstNumber = displayValue;
                displayValue = '';
                operator = singleOperatorButton.textContent;
                /* console.log(`Operator: ${operator}`);
                console.log(`First number : ${firstNumber}; display value ${displayValue}`); */
    })
});

equalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            secondNumber = displayValue;
      /* console.log(`secondNumber : ${secondNumber}`); */
            finalNumber = operate(Number(firstNumber), operator, Number(secondNumber));
            console.log(finalNumber);
})

resetButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            calculatorOutput.value = '';
      displayValue = '';
})
```

```html
<input id='calculatorOutput' type="text">
<button class="numberButtons" >0</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >1</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >2</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >3</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >4</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >5</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >6</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >7</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >8</button>
<button class="numberButtons" >9</button>
<button class="operatorButtons">+</button>
<button class="operatorButtons">-</button>
<button class="operatorButtons">*</button>
<button class="operatorButtons">/</button>
<button id="equalButton">=</button>
<button id="resetButton">С</button>
```

Comment: Rly, oh my God, thank you...
I've tried return, but that doesn't help me, but now everything is working XDD
Ty so much

Comment: @Riverain Maybe you didn't put all the `return`s. I've had to add 8 of them.

Comment: Yeah, seems like
Thank you very much, i don't know that the operate function needs the returns too